# out.print appearing outside of html tags

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to print from a loop in java, and then have it displayed in html. For some reason the printed material is being written outside of the table.

```
<table>
<%
...
while(rs.next()) {
    description = rs.getString("description");
    out.print("<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' class='style11'>" + description + "</tr>");
...
%>
</table>
```

Seems like it should work but the html file generated looks like this:

```
description1description2
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr class="style11" bgcolor="#ABCDEF"></tr>
      <tr class="style11" bgcolor="#ABCDEF"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using scriptlets is not recommended. Where is the closing brace for the while loop?

Comment: Is the HTML you are showing from an actual "view source" from the web browser?  Something is fishy, as I noticed that the "bgcolor" and "class" are reversed from the HTML vs. the JSP code.

Comment: @unekwu I'm still very new to Java Server Pages, how would I do this without a sriptlets? Would that require a servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Java, but HTML problem. You're missing `<td>...</td>`:

```
<table>
<%
...
while(rs.next()) {
    description = rs.getString("description");
    out.print("<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' class='style11'><td>" + description + "</td></tr>");
...
%>
</table>
```